# Large workspace variables affect multiplication runtime of unrelated variables

Tags: matlab, performance, multiplication

Old Title: *Small matrix multiplication *much slower* in R2016b than R2016a*
(**update** below)

I find that multiplication of small matrices seems much smaller in R2016b than R2016a. Here's a minimal example:

```
r = rand(50,100);
s = rand(100,100);
tic; r * s; toc
```

This takes about 0.0012s in R2016a and 0.018s R2016b.

Creating an artificial loop to make sure this isn't just some initial overhead or something leads to the same loss factor:

```
tic; for i = 1:1000, a = r*s; end, toc
```

This takes about 0.18s in R2016a and 2.1s R2016b.

Once I make the matrices much bigger, say `r = rand(500,1000);` and `s = rand(1000,1000)`, the version behave similarly (R2016b even seems to be ~15% faster). Anyone have any insight as to why this is, or can verify this behavior on another system?

I wonder if it has to do with the new arithmetic expansions implementation (if this feature has some cost for small matrix multiplication): http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/

---

**update**

After many tests, I discovered that this difference was not between MATLAB versions (my apologies). Instead, it seems to be a difference of what's in my base workspace... and worse, the type of variable that's in the base workspace.

I cleared a huge workspace (which had many large cell arrays with many small, differently sized matrix entries). If I clear the variables and do the timing of r*s, I get much faster runtime (x10-x100) than before the workspace was loaded.

So the question is, why does having variables in the workspace affect the matrix multiplication of two small variables? And even more, why does having certain types of variables slow down the workspace dramatically.

Here's an example where a large variable in cell form in the workspace affects the runtime of the matrix multiplication or two unrelated matrices. If I collapse this cell to a matrix, the effect goes away.

```
clear;
ticReps = 10000;
nCells = 100;
aa = rand(50,100); 
bb = rand(100, 100);

% test original timing
tic; for i = 1:ticReps, aa * bb; end
fprintf('original: %3.3f\n', toc);

% make some matrices inside a large number of cells
q = cell(nCells, nCells);
for i = 1:nCells * nCells
    q{i} = sprand(10000,10000, 0.0001);
end

% the timing again
tic; for i = 1:ticReps, aa * bb; end
fprintf('after large q cell: %3.3f\n', toc);

% make q into a matrix
q = cat(2, q{:});

% the timing again
tic; for i = 1:ticReps, aa * bb; end
fprintf('after large q matrix: %3.3f\n', toc);

clear q
% the timing again
tic; for i = 1:ticReps, aa * bb; end
fprintf('after clear q: %3.3f\n', toc);
```

In both staged, q takes up about 2Gb. Result:

```
original: 0.183
after large q cell: 0.320
after large q matrix: 0.175
after clear q: 0.184
```

Comment: I suspect that only the MathWorks could fully answer this question. However, I'd reccomend using `timeit` to accurately measure execution times, especially for small calculations.

Comment: I agree my inclination is that MathWorks are the main people who could answer. I've asked on Matlab Central just now. Thanks for the `timeit` suggestion -- the results seem consistent with the `tic`/`toc` above.

Comment: Just tried this on MacOS X and cannot confirm...

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified I am on Windows. Thank you for checking on OSX!

Comment: I've updated the question above with new findings. It seems like multiplication speed is affected by large cells in the workspace :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received an update from mathworks.

As far as I understand it, they say that this is the fault of the Windows memory manager, which allots memory to large cell arrays in a fairly fragmented manner. Since the (unrelated) multiplication needs memory (for the output), getting this piece of memory now takes longer time due to the memory fragmentation caused by the cell. Linux (as tested) does not have this issue.